# How to open a specific tab using a link from other page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that opens it's specific content using buttons or tab. But in my navbar, some buttons of navbar needs to direct in an open tab. I used window.location.hash but still not working.
Is there any other javascript that can open the tab using button links from other pages?

One of my navbar buttons has a code like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="service.html#tranSection" style="color: #efdf4e;">transfer</a>
```

```js
function serviceDisplay(evt, serviceName) {
  var i, serviceSection, bar_item;
  serviceSection = document.getElementsByClassName("serviceSection");
  for (i = 0; i < serviceSection.length; i++) {
    serviceSection[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  bar_item = document.getElementsByClassName("bar_item");
  for (i = 0; i < bar_item.length; i++) {
    bar_item[i].className = bar_item[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(serviceName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var openTab = $(location.hash).filter(".serviceSection");

if (openTab.length) {
  $("a[href='" + location.hash + "']").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-bar">
  <a href="#depSection" data-toggle="tab"><button onclick="serviceDisplay(event, 'depSection')" type="button" class="bar_item dep-btn" id="defaultOpen">deposit</button></a>
  <a href="#withSection" data-toggle="tab"><button onclick="serviceDisplay(event, 'withSection')" type="button" class="bar_item with-btn">withdraw</button></a>
  <a href="#tranSection" data-toggle="tab"><button onclick="serviceDisplay(event, 'tranSection')" type="button" class="bar_item tran-btn">transfer</button></a>
  <a href="#histSection" data-toggle="tab"><button onclick="serviceDisplay(event, 'histSection')" type="button" class="bar_item history-btn">history</button></a>
</div>

<div id="depSection" class="serviceSection">
  DEPOSIT
</div>
<div id="withSection" class="serviceSection">
  WITHDRAW
</div>
<div id="tranSection" class="serviceSection">
  TRANSFER
</div>
<div id="histSection" class="serviceSection">
  HISTORY
</div>
```

Comment: did you try using target="_blank" in your anchor link to open in a new tab?

Answer (score -1):

Parse url with a regular expression and use parsed data to open tab